# Mapear porta da Api num projeto MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Criei um projeto MVC e dentro uma API.

Preciso pegar a API quando eu subir o projeto no (F5).

Exemplo, criei um serviço que é um GET em minha tabela de Tipo.

De que forma eu consigo mapear a API para poder pegar dentro de uma controller MVC?

Meu projeto é Asp.Net MVC e dentro dele tenho um projeto Web API, os serviços estão no Web API e pelo MVC devo pegar o serviço e preencher umas Views.

Esse método funciona dentro do serviço API, mas agora com MVC não sei como chamar.

```
public class GetCidades
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();

        public List<Cidade> getCidades()
        {
            var result = banco.Database.SqlQuery<Cidade>("sp_cons_cidade").ToList();

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Como eu pego esse serviço dentro do MVC. Fiz isso

```
public class GetCidades
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        List<Cidade> cidades = new List<Cidade>();

        public async Task<List<Cidade>> GetCidadesAsync()
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:51381/api/";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var _cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cidade>>(response);
            return _cidade;
        }
    }
```

Mas não sei mais o que fazer.

Preciso mapear alguma coisa? Porque quando dou F5 sobe as duas, certo, MVC e API e de dentro do MVC como eu pego a API?

**EDIT1**

Minha controller dentro do MVC

```
public class GetCidadeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: GetCidade
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetCidades()
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
```

A controller da API

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetCidadesController : ApiController
    {
        GetCidades cidades = new GetCidades();

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<Cidade> getCidades()
        {
            return cidades.getCidades().AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }

    }
```

Perdido. Nem sei se é assim que se deve fazer

Comment: Fazendo um request ou post de acordo com o verbo aceito pelo método?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, amigo, como eu faço isso? Eu não sei fazer isso.

Comment: @pnet está na hora de dar uma reavaliada na forma que você pergunta as coisas aqui no site. Tens recebido [negativos](https://i.imgur.com/KJHcF69.png) um atrás do outro.

Comment: Só downvote nessa semana, é a semana ou o mês dos downvotes

Comment: @pnet mas com todo respeito, as perguntas estão mal formuladas mesmo. Dificilmente ela vai ajudar outras pessoas da forma que está elaborada (se é que é possível responder de maneira clara até para seup problema específico, já que talvez nem ajudar você consigamos por causa da dificuldade de compreensão das perguntas)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, concordo com você plenamente. Mas a dúvida é grande e às vezes não sei o que fazer. Vou tentar melhorar as perguntas. Realmente tá muito ampla

Comment: @pnet coloque mais trechos de código, mais coisas que você tenha testado. Se você colocar isso, fica mais fácil de a gente ajudar.

Comment: Blz, temos um pouco de código, agora foque em descrever o erro

Comment: São dois projetos diferentes dentro de uma mesma solution e você configurou para uppar  os dois?

Comment: Apaguem os comentários para não poluir mais a pergunta, e eventualmente ficar mais fácil ajudar na solução da pergunta

Comment: Fui em propriedades da solution e marquei que o projeto depende da API. Agora acho que sobe os dois, certo ou não?

Comment: @pnet, não conheço direito o mundo do c#, mas acho que dá pra fazer uma comparação, no laravel você tem um ambiente API e um ambiente WEB, você tem isso no seu projeto e não sabe como fazer um se comunicar com o outro..... é isso?

Comment: Isso, @MarceloBoni, isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente apontar o navegador para /api/[nome do seu controller, sem o sufixo controller]/[nome do seu método ou action]

Esse é o mapeamento padrão.
Se puder postar sua classe Startup.cs e o controller aqui dá pra ser mais preciso.

Me parece que você não está colocando seu serviço dentro de um controller. No projeto de Web.Api, você deve ter uma classe que herda de Controller. Nesta classe, um método chamado Get() onde neste método você usa seu "GetCidades" e retorna o que ele retornar.

Acho que está faltando entender como o Asp.Net funciona, dá uma olhada nesse link que pode te ajudar: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Eu não tenho a classe Startup.cs. Meu projeto é Asp.Net MVC e dentro dele um projeto Web API, os serviços estão no Web API e pelo MVC devo pegar o serviço e preencher umas Views.

Comment: @pnet pra começo de conversa: essa era uma informação que já deveria estar na pergunta. Não fazendo isso, você induz o Autor da resposta falhar.

Comment: andrecarlucci, se eu faço dessa forma eu não consigo pegar a API. Preciso mapear alguma coisa? Porque quando dou F5 sobe as duas, certo, MVC e API e de dentro do MVC como eu pego a API?

Comment: andre, eu fiz o projeto primeiro em web api e consegui pegar os serviços, mas depois que tive que criar um MVC e com ele consumir o Web API, aí não consegui mais.

Comment: Se tem os serviços, poderia postar o controller pra gente?

Comment: Resolvido pela resposta do andre. Tá dando outro erro aqui mas isso é outro POST